# "In the earthquake" vs. "from the earthquake" vs. "because of the earthquake"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Improvement-

> In 2001, hundreds of people were killed **from** the earthquake in Wakanda.

options - 'in', 'because of'

1. Which is more appropriate? ( my book says 'in' but 'because of' can be used here as an adverb as it explains why they were killed?)
2. Please tell me where I can use 'because of' apart from as an adverb in a sentence.

Comment: **because of {X}** is actually a compressed form of **by cause of {X}**; over time the two words **by cause** have morphed into a single word. Nowadays people label **because of** a compound preposition; it presents the noun-phrase {X} as the explanation or reason for something.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of **from** doesn't work in your example.

**From** is used in certain contexts such as **died from snake-bite** or **died from sepsis** but not died from natural events or accidents.

People are said to die **in** explosions, plagues, accidents, floods, earthquakes, plane crashes and the like.

To say that people were killed (or died) **in** an earthquake suggests that their deaths occurred immediately or soon after, as bridges and buildings collapsed. To say that they died **because of** the earthquake suggests that it was as a result of the earthquake, possibly of hunger weeks or months later.

Similarly, to say that people died **in an explosion** means at the time. To say that they died **because of** an explosion might refer to injuries that led to their deaths subsequently.

**Because of** is preferred when you are referring to a cause or allocating blame or guilt, especially for some action or policy. Thus

> The child died because of/as a result of the motorist's carelessness.
>
> The famine occurred because of/as a result of the government's policy of taxing farmers.
>
> The fuel price rose because of/as a result of the shortage of supplies.

Comment: In all these cases **because of** is used as an adverb right?

Comment: @RitwikBhattacharyya *Because* is usually a conjunction (or subordinating conjunction). But used with *of*, some grammarians regard it as a *compound preposition*. **In Standard English, the word “because” can be used two ways. One of them is to introduce a clause, as in “Aardvark was late because he was waiting for the repairman to show up.” Used this way, “because” is a subordinating conjunction. The other is to team up with “of” to form what’s called a compound preposition.** https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/because-has-become-a-preposition-because-grammar/

Comment: I get your point. Please have a look at this and tell me if this link is wrong. He mentioned 'because of' is used as an adverb. But you are saying it's a compound preposition.

http://web.ku.edu/~edit/because.html

Comment: @RitwikBhattacharyya The word *because* in itself is a  conjunction, not an adverb. But *because * can be used to introduce an adverb phrase or clause. See http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-adverb-clauses.html .  Also see the explanation of *because* introducing prepositional phrase.   
 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144778/what-part-of-speech-will-the-new-because-be